# Dirac Delta transformation

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, dirac-delta

So I have the following definition of the Dirac Delta -

$$\delta_{D}(x) = \lim_{a\to0} U(x; -a,a)$$

Where U is the continuous uniform distribution.

My question is, what would $\delta_{D}(x-a)$ be? Would it be

$$\delta_{D}(x-a) = \lim_{a\to0} U(x-a; -a,a)$$
or
$$\delta_{D}(x-a) = \lim_{a\to0} U(x; 0,2a)$$

I'm just not entirely sure what this graph would look like.

Comment: According to that "definition," $\delta_D(x-a) = \lim_{b \to 0} U(x;a-b,a+b)$.

Comment: Methinks you are simply making the mistake of using $a$ with two different meanings in the same expression (the middle one in your post, for $\delta_{D}(x-a)$): in one use it's a constant, and in the other use it goes to zero. @FabioSomenzi rewrites your expression so as to correct this.